# Nginx ssl proxy for Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, ssl

I am running the following setup:

[public ip]-nginx_proxy-[lan]-apache_server

SSL is configured and set up on the nginx proxy level (and this is working).

However, when I visit a site over ssl, I get .css and .js files returned over http (which are blocked by the browser). It seems like Apache is unaware that the client is requesting content over ssl.

This is my current config:

nginx:

```
server {
    listen              443;
    server_name         maiev.domain.com, ~.;

    ssl             on;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.pem;

    access_log          off;
    error_log           off;

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ /\.git {
                deny all;
        }

    location / {
        proxy_pass      http://maiev.local:80;
            proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            add_header              Front-End-Https on;
            proxy_redirect          off;
    }
}
```

This is my Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin help@domain.com
    ServerName dev.domain.com

    <IfModule rpaf_module>
        RPAFenable On
        RPAFsethostname On
        RPAFproxy_ips 172.16.1.130
        RPAFheader X-Forwarded-For
    </IfModule>

    DocumentRoot /home/sites/www/dev-domain/public 

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/sites/www/dev-domain/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /home/sites/logs/dev-domain/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /home/sites/logs/dev-domain/access.log combined
    php_value log_errors on
    php_value error_log /home/sites/logs/dev-domain/php.log
</VirtualHost>
```

If I change the $scheme to https in the nginx config, nothing changes.

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe this isn't apache fault. Did your web apps aware of `X-Forwarded-Proto` header?

Comment: How exactly would you expect apache to know that you're using SSL when you're handling the SSL outside of apache?

Comment: And it is not the actual content that references the `.css` and `.js` using absolute URL's  (using plain HTTP) instead of relative ones?

Comment: We don't use absolute URLs. It's all relative. So I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @JennyD: Front-End-Https on; & X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

Answer (score 0):

If you set your url to 'http://...' in your html file, it will be used as http, not converted to https magically because referrer is using https. So your probably need to fix your application and not you web server.

Comment: We use relative URLs. There are no `http://domain.com` links anywhere in our (laravel) website.

Comment: Check with some developer tools, what urls are loaded. There might be some images requested from css or some js loading some http url, that you did not accounted for.